NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined when running model.fit() in TensorFlow 2.10 environment
I'm developing a model in a Conda environment and encountering an issue when trying to train my model with model.fit(). Here are the details:
TensorFlow version: 2.10.0
Python version: 3.9.20
Environment: Conda.
Btw, I tried installing scipy with pip and conda. Nothing happened.
Error code:
{
    "name": "NameError",
    "message": "name 'scipy' is not defined",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 3
      1 import scipy
----> 3 results = model.fit(train_image_gen,epochs=20,
      4                               validation_data=test_image_gen,
      5                              callbacks=[early_stop])

File c:\\Users\\burak\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\utils\\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\\Users\\burak\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\preprocessing\\image.py:2529, in apply_affine_transform(x, theta, tx, ty, shear, zx, zy, row_axis, col_axis, channel_axis, fill_mode, cval, order)
   2485 @keras_export(\"keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform\")
   2486 def apply_affine_transform(
   2487     x,
   (...)
   2499     order=1,
   2500 ):
   2501     \"\"\"Applies an affine transformation specified by the parameters given.
   2502 
   2503     Args:
   (...)
   2527         ImportError: if SciPy is not available.
   2528     \"\"\"
-> 2529     if scipy is None:
   2530         raise ImportError(
   2531             \"Image transformations require SciPy. \" \"Install SciPy.\"
   2532         )
   2534     # Input sanity checks:
   2535     # 1. x must 2D image with one or more channels (i.e., a 3D tensor)
   2536     # 2. channels must be either first or last dimension

NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined"
}

Code:
results = model.fit(train_image_gen,epochs=20,
                              validation_data=test_image_gen,
                             callbacks=[early_stop])

